Python and SAP GUI Scripting Error : pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221020, 'Invalid syntax', None, None)
I'm trying to write a automation script that does task on SAP. For this I'm using Python and win32com package, I'm getting the following error when I try to connect to SAP.
Traceback (most recent call last):   
win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI") File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 86, in GetObject     return Moniker(Pathname, clsctx) File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 103, in Moniker     moniker, i, bindCtx = pythoncom.MkParseDisplayName(Pathname) 
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221020, 'Invalid syntax', None, None)

This is my code
import pythoncom, win32com.client

def sapLogin():
    try:
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()

        sap_gui = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
        application = sap_gui.GetScriptingEngine
        connection = application.OpenConnection("QA", True)
        connection = application.Children(0)
        session = connection.Children(0)
        session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize

    finally:
        pythoncom.CoUninitialize()

sapLogin()

error is on this line: sap_gui = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI").
Scripting is enabled on SAP, and I open SAP before running my script.

Maybe this could be related: did you try to change your SAP GUI settings in the scripting block? Also, is your SAP GUI software installed locally or is it inside a virtual desktop application?

It looks like certain imports and initialization statements could fix this problem. Please check this forum
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61429270/error-with-win32com-client-getobject-when-connecting-to-sap-gui and this forum https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860185/python-cant-import-wmi-under-special-circumstance
